# Dataset + Experiment Run tracking

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Can't see associated run in Dataset pages in Azure ML Workspace

I want to see when & where dataset was used in the experiment. But I can't see it. I tried [tutorial notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/datasets/datasets-tutorial/tabular-dataset-tutorial.ipynb).

```py
run.get_details()
```

output

```
'containerInstance': {'cpuCores': 2, 'memoryGb': 3.5, 'region': None},  
'data': {},  
'dataReferences': {},...
```

Detail log doesn't show any dataset information as above. And no associated run in dataset page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C20rv.png)

I want to confirm that my dataset was used in the experiment from ...

1. run.get_details()
2. Workspace Dataset page

Any workaround on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. We are working on adding the tracking to retrieve dataset from Experiment run at the moment. Will publish documentations and tutorials once the feature is released.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question.  We are adding the logging to get_by_name().  As a work around, in your training code, you can do

```
Dataset.get()
```

instead of

```
Dataset.get_by_name()
```

and then it will be there.  You should see

```
 'azureml.dataset.get.titanic dataset:1': '{"name": "titanic dataset", "definition": "1", "snapshot": ""}'}
```